# JavaFX 1.0 released. What are your thoughts?

Tags: javafx

**[JavaFX 1.0](http://www.javafx.com/)** was released on Thursday, Dec. 4.

As a developer, what do you think of JavaFX?  In your workplace, do you have any plans to move forward with JavaFX-based apps or websites?  Do you have near-term plans to learn JavaFX?

Answer (score 3):

JavaFX is the only open RIA platform, so I believe it will catch up with competition sooner or later.

It looks pretty good for 1.0 version. Demos are well documented and offer everything I need.

There are some problems of course. Java applet seems improved a little, but it's still way behind. Loading took long time with high cpu load. It didn't show any progress, like usual flash application do, so user can't be sure if his internet is slow, applet is big or java is slow. I also had to accept certificate, even more than one in some demos.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly think it is worth a look as it looks like RIAs are here to stay and the more platforms/choices, the better. Sun sure is way behind though considering Micrsoft was late to the game with Siliverlight and still way ahead of Sun. If nothing else, I would like to see what Sun did differently with their implementation from Adobe and Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to learn, that I want to learn, that I don't have time to learn.

Looks promising, but I agree with others. It has an uphill battle and I have my doubts that it will prevail in the long run. One positive of Java FX is that it'll prolong my career-investment into the Java language.

It may also encourage more RIA platforms to emerge on the JVM--so while Java may decline, the JVM can continue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell JavaFX is falling flat on it's face. I've looked at the demos and example source code and I'm not impressed. JavaFX has an uphill battle to compete with Adobe and Silverlight which have already been in the wild for some time. Note that I'm a long time Java developer.

Answer (score 0):

I like the concept of JavaFX, but haven't had the chance to do anything with it.  I don't normally do Internet Apps, so I have to go out of my way to try out the latest platforms.